# How do I toggle the css display of DIVs to show one and hide the others based on buttons clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code where if I click a button, the corresponding div's `display` will be set to "block":

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="Ideas" class="btn btn-info" onclick=toggle_visibility("one")>Ideas</button>
<button id="Problem" class="btn btn-info" onclick=toggle_visibility('two')>Problem </button>
<button id="Question" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Question</button>
<button id="Praise" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Praise</button>
<br>
<section class="content">  
  <div id="one">
    <h1>Ideas</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/feedback">
      {{ render_field(form.test_field, class_='form-control')}}
      {{ render_field(form.title, class_='form-control') }}
      {{ render_field(form.information, class_='form-control') }}
      <input type = "submit" value = "submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="two" style="display:none">
    <form method="post" action="/feedbackpb">
      <h1>Problem</h1>
      {{ render_field(form.test_field, class_='form-control')}}
      {{ render_field(form.title, class_='form-control') }}
      {{ render_field(form.information, class_='form-control') }}
      <input type = "submit" value = "submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, what I need here is that on button click, all these DIVs display should be set to none except for the div corresponding with the button I click.

Comment: Your onlick=toggle_visibility needs the id of the form control to toggle. If you like to toggle multiple id's just add more toggle_visibility - like this: onlick="toggle_visibility('id1');toggle_visibility('id2)"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding an inline `onclick` listener on each button, just replace it with a data attribute instead with the name of the corresponding id of the div that you want to hide as it's value. Also, you need to add a common class name for all your divs, say `box` so you can loop through them later.

After adding the attribute values, you can now add an event listener to all your buttons and pass their respective dataset value as a parameter for your `toggle_visibility()` function.

Now inside the function, assign all the `box` divs to a variable using `querySelectorAll()` and just simply loop through the list of divs, compare every single div's id with the data attribute value in the parameter and set it's display to `block` while setting the display for the rest of the divs to `none`.

---

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/tu7m8z9o/52/) or the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the above:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id]');

function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div.box");
  
  boxes.forEach(box => {
      if(box.id == id) {
          box.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          box.style.display = "none";
      }
  })
}

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  var x= function() { toggle_visibility(btn.dataset.id) };
 btn.addEventListener("click", x);
});
```

```html
    <button id="Ideas" class="btn btn-info" data-id="one">Ideas</button>
    <button id="Problem" class="btn btn-info" data-id="two">Problem</button>
    <button id="Ideas2" class="btn btn-info" data-id="three">Ideas2</button>
    <button id="Problem2" class="btn btn-info" data-id="four">Problem2</button>

    <button id="Question" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Question</button>
<button id="Praise" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Praise</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="box" id="one">
        <h1>Ideas</h1>
        <p>
          Some Form Here
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="two">
        <h1>Problem</h1>
        <p>
          Some Form Here
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="three">
        <h1>Ideas2</h1>
        <p>
          Some Form Here
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="four">
        <h1>Problem2</h1>
        <p>
          Some Form Here
        </p>
    </div>
```

### BUT WHAT IF I WANT TO DISPLAY ALL THE DIVs TOGETHER AGAIN?

You can just add another button to your list and add a separate click listener to the button that runs a function, say `showAllPanels()` that displays all the divs again as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/tu7m8z9o/54/) or in the **Code Snippet** below:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div.box");
  
  boxes.forEach(box => {
      if(box.id == id) {
          box.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          box.style.display = "none";
      }
  })
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id]');
var showAll = document.getElementById("showAll");

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  var x= function() { toggle_visibility(btn.dataset.id) };
 btn.addEventListener("click", x);
});


function showAllPanels(){
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div.box");
  
  boxes.forEach(box => {
   box.style.display = "block";
  });
  
}

showAll.addEventListener('click', showAllPanels);
```

```html
<button id="Ideas" class="btn btn-info" data-id="one">Ideas</button>
<button id="Problem" class="btn btn-info" data-id="two">Problem</button>
<button id="Ideas2" class="btn btn-info" data-id="three">Ideas2</button>
<button id="Problem2" class="btn btn-info" data-id="four">Problem2</button>
    
<button id="Question" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Question</button>
<button id="Praise" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href ='/'">Praise</button>

<button id="showAll" class="btn btn-info">Show All</button>
<hr>
<div class="box" id="one">
    <h1>Ideas</h1>
    <p>
      Some Form Here
    </p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="two">
    <h1>Problem</h1>
    <p>
      Some Form Here
    </p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="three">
    <h1>Ideas2</h1>
    <p>
      Some Form Here
    </p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="four">
    <h1>Problem2</h1>
    <p>
      Some Form Here
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When I used it on Notepad++ and Pycharm (Html) , I was not able to have the same output as you. Was there a problem. I checked the jsFiddle and Code Snippet, I works perfectly. Why is that so?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Try downloading some other notepad++ alternative and see if the problem persists.